# Pointer address and reference confusion

Tags: c++, pointers

I have two nearly identical pieces of code which should produce the same output, except not only are they different, the one line I changed is somehow affecting unrelated output!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Tag {
public:
    int num = 0;
    Tag* contains = nullptr;

    Tag::Tag(int n) { num = n; }

    void setContains(Tag t) { contains = &t; }

    int getNum() { return num; }
    Tag getContains() { return *contains; }
};

int main() {
    Tag tag1 = Tag(1); Tag tag2 = Tag(2);
    tag1.setContains(tag2);
    cout << tag1.getContains().getNum() << endl << (*tag1.contains).getNum() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs

```
8460735
8460735
```

or some other random number. Which tells me I'm somehow outputting the pointer address and not the object it's referencing. So I changed the line

```
cout << tag1.getContains().getNum() << endl << (*tag1.contains).getNum() << endl;
```

to

```
cout << tag1.getContains().getNum() << endl << (*tag1.contains).num << endl;
```

and I get the output

```
2
2
```

Wait, what? I get it if the second line changes from the address to the actual number 2, but why do BOTH change to 2?

Comment: try activating warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setContains` makes `contains` point to a local variable. The variable is destroyed as soon as the function returns, leaving `contains` a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use it then exhibits undefined behavior.

Practically speaking, `contains->num` reads some random garbage from the stack where the variable used to live. Slight perturbations to the program change stack access patterns, leaving different garbage there.

Comment: I see. So I should use a pointer to a Tag's address in the argument of setContains rather than the Tag itself? And if you can elaborate further, why wouldn't this make my (*tag1.contains).num line output something weird, rather than the number 2 as it did? Since tag1.contains is a dangling pointer, how does *tag1.contains resolve to the actual tag when tag1.getContains() doesn't?

Comment: Fewer function calls means fewer writes to the stack. The memory location where `2` used to live just happens not to be overwritten yet in one case, and is overwritten with something else in the other.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you'are invoking undefined behavior, you save the address of a local argument to `Tag* contains` here:

```
void setContains(Tag t) { contains = &t; }
```

You should pass the argument by reference or pointer directly. Otherwise you are just saving the address of a variable on stack which is destroyed at function exit.

Everything based on `contains` afterwards is just undefined behavior.